# Grouping based on field change

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a mysql table that contains events with data attached. I need to group these events on change. I only want to return "Running". In the example below it should return two groups. Currently I have it returning one group for anything with the event "running", when I require two, i.e split by event. There is no link to the ID, it is random.

```
id    Event     Seconds
1     Running   34
2     Running   12
2     Walking   43
2     Running   45
3     Running   67
3     Running   32
4     Walking   12
```

Hopefully some bright spark out there will be able to help me.

Comment: Please add to your question what you've tried, the results you're getting, and the desired results.

Comment: Please elaborate... what are you doing with the "Walking" rows? Are you summing the Seconds?

Comment: I wanted to create an array and create a new index on change of "Event" with seconds summed, so i would have 4 results for the example shown. I have actually got round this now my using vb.net.